# Use different math font in inline-style and display-style formulas for \int symbol

Tags: math-mode, math-fonts, displaystyle, mathabx

I have seen [Use different math font in inline-style and display-style formulas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249760/use-different-math-font-in-inline-style-and-display-style-formulas), but here I just want one symbol to be different inline vs display. In [Borrowing the integral and summation signs from mathabx package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580779/borrowing-the-integral-and-summation-signs-from-mathabx-package), we are taught how to use the integral symbol in the `mathabx` package, but what if I want to use the standard integral sign in inline TeX, i.e. `\textstyle`, but the `mathabx` integral in `\displaystyle`? I don't want two different commands that produce each respective symbol, but instead just one command `\int` that changes its behavior based on the context in which it is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a fan of mixing glyphs from different fonts, but here you go...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for \ilimits@

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{<->mathx10}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathxintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B3}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\int}{\DOTSI\mathop{\mathchoice{\mathxintop}{\intop}{\intop}{\intop}}\ilimits@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

See $\int$ and $\displaystyle\int_{\int_{\int}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]